# Extracting corresponding values of particular number from a large matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, extract

I have a matrix 2x5000 matrix with the stimulus value (1 to 7) and corresponding responses. Stimulus values are randomly scattered across the data. 
Like:

```
2   0
3   1
3   1
1   1
7   0
6   0
7   1
6   1
1   0
1   0
7   1
6   1
4   1
```

I need to calculate the mean of the responses for each value of the stimulus (e.g I need 7 means here).

But I don't know how to separate the values and it's corresponding values in different variables (how to extract 6 for example and it's corresponding data).

It's getting trickier for the second similar matrix with added noise to original values, where I had a hope to extract 1 to 1.9, ... 6 to 6.9 and corresponding values.

I was trying find(data_experiment == 4) (for example) and it returns positions of all 4s in my 2x5000 matrix, but I have no idea how to extract the corresponding data.

Is there anything better than 'find'?

Can anyone suggest what functions can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [accumarray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) function, that was designed to solve it:

Here is a sample code:

```
D = [2   0
     3   1
     3   1
     1   1
     7   0
     6   0
     7   1
     6   1
     1   0
     1   0
     7   1
     6   1
     4   1];

%Compute sums: 
%Result: S(1) sumSecCol(where FirstCol = 1), S(2) = sumSecCol(where FirstCol = 2), S(3) = sumSecCol(where FirstCol = 3), 
S = accumarray(D(:,1), D(:,2));

%Compute count (replace D(:,2) with "1"s):
C = accumarray(D(:,1), ones(size(D,1), 1));

%Remove zeros from C - to avoid division by zero
C = max(C, 1);

%Compute mean
M = S ./ C;
```

Result:

```
M =

    0.3333
         0
    1.0000
    1.0000
         0
    0.6667
    0.6667
```

---

Fore the noise case "1 to 1.9, ... 6 to 6.9", you can use `floor` function:

```
D = floor(D);
```

1 to 1.9999 goes to 1, 2 to 2.9999 goes to 2...

It looks like `round` is more subtitle, but the operation you describe applies `floor`.

---

Here is a solution using for loop, without using `accumarray`:

```
S = zeros(7, 1);
C = zeros(7, 1);

D1 = D(:, 1); %First column
D2 = D(:, 2); %Second column

for i = 1:7
    S(i) = sum(D2(D1 == i));
    C(i) = sum(D1 == i);
end

M = S ./ max(C, 1);
```

Instead of using `find`, it's recommended to use [logical indexing](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/) as above.

Comment: Or `M = accumarray(D(:,1), D(:,2), [], @mean);`

Comment: Thank's, I learned about `accumarray` function from one of your previous answers. I still have a lot to learn...

Comment: Honestly, Thank you so much, guys! I am incredibly grateful for the replies and the possibility to learn from you.